# Dual channel the same in CMZ16GX3M4A1600C9 or 4 CMZ4GX3M1A1600C9?

Tags: memory, computer-building, overclocking

I'm trying to decide between buying a 16GB ([CMZ16GX3M4A1600C9](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233143)) kit or 4 individual 4GB modules ([CMZ4GX3M1A1600C9](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233141)).

For some reason the place I'm getting them from (not newegg) its cheaper to buy the second option but I'm wondering if they will still be working at dual channel with no problem or if there is any other risk/downside of buying them individually.

Comment: Note that the kit of 4 only costs **3 cents more** than 4 singles. (Based on neweggs prices from the link's posted.)

Comment: I live in Mexico, the online store that I use has the kit ~$30 USD more expensive

Answer (score 0):

They are the exact same modules.  If you can get them for less buying them individually, then go for it!